# Why is a 2D->2D tSNE transformation not idempotent (up to random influences)?

Tags: tsne

My understanding of tSNE is that probability distributions are optimized in a way to maintain Euclidean (by default) distances (on average) when transforming from the input to the output space. If that is the case, when transforming from 2D to another 2D space, wouldn't the identity transformation be the ideal tSNE? I know that tSNE transformation is a somewhat random process, but I'd expect distances to be maintained generally.

By contrast, when applying a tSNE to the following data, the result has a very different distribution of distances. Note in particular the distribution of red dots:

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

This example has been produced using

```py
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
tsne = TSNE(random_state=1).fit_transform(data)
```

compare https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html

Comment: Have you looked at your distances matrices ? It is fairly possible that two differents looking graphes have similar distance matrices.

Comment: tSNE does not preserve distance, here is a good blog that presents various experiments with t-SNE : https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Comment: @mprouveur thanks, that's a good read! "The t-SNE algorithm adapts its notion of “distance” to regional density variations in the data set. As a result, it naturally expands dense clusters, and contracts sparse ones, evening out cluster sizes."